# Not able to open a .xlsx file using the load_workbook by openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a .xlsx sheet with a huge filename like this: `child_id_survey_918_choose_touching_results_1541687696.xlsx` when I try to use the load_workbook() to load this file it gives me a weird error.

My python file and the excel sheet both lie in the same folder.
CODE:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
workbook = load_workbook('child_id_survey_918_choose_touching_results_1541687696.xlsx')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    workbook = load_workbook('child_id_survey_918_choose_touching_results_1541687696.xlsx')
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 280, in read
    self.read_worksheets()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 228, in read_worksheets
    ws_parser.bind_all()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py", line 434, in bind_all
    self.bind_cells()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py", line 337, in bind_cells
    for idx, row in self.parser.parse():
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py", line 153, in parse
    row = self.parse_row(element)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py", line 274, in parse_row
    cells = [self.parse_cell(el) for el in row]
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py", line 274, in <listcomp>
    cells = [self.parse_cell(el) for el in row]
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py", line 181, in parse_cell
    style_id = int(style_id)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'string'
```

I have also tried using this: `workbook = load_workbook(filename = 'child_id_survey_918_choose_touching_results_1541687696.xlsx')`

Why am I getting this error and how can I solve it?

Comment: There is no problem with the file name, I tested it. There might be a problem with a column or row id where it is an invalid literal for an integer so it spits out an error when it tries to read in the data.

Comment: is there any other way to open an existing .xlsx file and edit its contents and save it back in the same file without using openpyxl??

Comment: Added something to my answer!

Comment: This looks like a problem with the file. You can submit a bug report on the openpyxl bugtracker.